# Regex for single digits and single digit with decimal only

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time coming up with the most suitable regex for my needs.

I want a regex that only validates numbers from 1-8, with or without a decimal point

```
1 // Valid
3 // Valid
8 // Valid

2.00 // Valid
4.45 // Valid
7.60 // Valid

9 // Invalid
10 // Invalid
9.00 // Invalid
50.40 // invalid
```

So far this is what I came up with, but `^([0-8]$\.?[0-8]*|\.[0-8]+)` but this only accepts numbers from 1-8, and nothing with a decimal. Can someone kindly provide a suitable regex for this example?

Comment: The decimal value can only be 0-8 to?

Comment: `^[0-8](?:.\d+)?$` or if the decimals can only be up to 8 `^[0-8](?:.[0-8]+)?$`

Comment: the question wasn't very clear but the requirement is finding out if a number is 0 >= x <= 8 ... and those comments don't take that into account. They still stick with the idea that 8 has the chance to be followed by decimal places.. I hope the OP will be more clear about that

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would be better to limit regex to string parsing. My best approach would be to parse a valid number from the string and then convert it to number before doing any validation on its value as being < x

But if you really want to go via regex (and it will be hard to change in case) would be with something like:

```
^0*([0-7](\.\d+)?|8)$
```

It matches `any number between 0 and 8` ... decimal point is allowed if followed by numbers and the highest valid number like that would be `7.999999999...` followed by the next valid integer number being `8`.

Trailing zeros are considered.